# differential in integration cancelled but variable endpoint is changed

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, physics

In kinetic energy equation in [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy).
I have difficulty problem how endpoint in integral change from t to v.
This doesn't look like it is using substitution method.

$\mathcal{E}_{k}=\int_{0}^{t}\boldsymbol{F}\ dx=\int_{0}^{t}\boldsymbol{v}\cdot d(m\boldsymbol{v})=\int_{0}^{v}d(\frac{mv^2}{2})=\frac{mv^2}{2}$

I'm not sure how to relate if you cancel differential dx as in above,
you can change the interval endpoint [0,t] to [0,v].

Comment: What you wrote is not correct. When changing variables we must change bounds. Perhaps this is also wrong in the wiki? Yep. Poor notation at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me write the offending calculation with correct change of bounds. Suppose $F=ma$ where $a = dv/dt$ then suppose $E_k = \int_0^x F dx$. We calculate,
$$ E_k = \int_{x_o}^{x_f} F dx =\int_{t_o}^{t_f}  \frac{dx}{dt}dt =\int_{t_o}^{t_f} mv\frac{dv}{dt} dt = 
\int_{v_0}^{v_f} mvdv  = \frac{1}{2}mv_f^2-\frac{1}{2}mv_o^2$$
where I have used $t_o$ for the initial time and $t_f$ for the final time etc.

Comment: sorry if I never phrase it better but I have trouble understanding just because you cancelled dt, doesn't mean the interval [t0,tf] can be changed to interval [v0,vf]

Comment: okay, I think I need to go back and relearn integration.I think you are using t=v substitution but since dt is already cancelled, there's no dv.I think I overcomplicated it hence the confusion.thanks for your help.

Comment: @kypronite it's as simple as this: the bounds must match the measure. When I have $dt$ we have $t$-bounds, when $dx$ there are $x$-bounds and finally, with $dv$ I change to $v$-bounds. All of this assumes there is some unique correspondence between $t,x$ and $v$. See page 249 theorem 7.5.21 of http://www.supermath.info/OldschoolCalculusII.pdf for my proof of the change of variables theorem for one variable.